# Javascript to allow only one textbox to contain a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox

I have 2 textboxes that are optional, and only 1 can contain data.  I need it to dynamically enable/disable the other textbox when one has something entered into it. By default they should both be enabled but then one should disable when something is entered in the other. I had this working with the code below, but now it doesn't seem to do it. Its basically checking every half-second to see if a value is entered.

```
setInterval(function(){
if ($("input[name=audioUri]").val().length != 0) {
    $("input[name=videoUri]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("input[name=audioUri]").attr("disabled", "");
} else if ($("input[name=videoUri]").val().length != 0) {
    $("input[name=audioUri]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("input[name=videoUri]").attr("disabled", "");
} else {
    $("input[name=videoUri]").attr("disabled", "");
    $("input[name=audioUri]").attr("disabled", "");     
}} , 500);
```

It checks to see if there are already values in the textboxes when the page loads and determines what to do from there, but when I first load up the page, both boxes are getting disabled. It's almost like they think there is something in the textboxes already. When I check the value of the boxes it is the empty string "", maybe I should check for .val() != ""?

I'm thinking there might be a better way to handle it without needing the setInterval function. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/7mKzy/1/

Comment: All were good answers, I sorta used bits from a few of them. Updated with JSfiddle example.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the event .change() on your textbox. So each time there is a change in your textbox. You call a function to enable or disable the other textbox.

```
$("#IdTextbox").change(function () {
        yourFunction();
    });
```

To check if your textbox has some data use :

```
if ($('#txt').val() != "") {
           doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could try `keyup` or `keypress`, which will trigger when the user starts entering text.

Answer (score 1):

Let both enabled, and don't use set interval.
Use the parameter `onChange` or `keyup` or `keypress` on the text box to call an function that verify if there is something new on the box, and do the enable/disable.

Answer (score 1):

Do it on `keydown()` and use `prop()`:

```
$('input[name=audioUri]').keydown(function(){
    if (!$(this).val()) {  
        $('input[name=videoUri]').prop("disabled", true); 
    }
});
```

And to check on load, just do it on DOM ready:

```
$(function(){
    if (!$('input[name=audioUri]').val()) {  
        $('input[name=videoUri]').prop("disabled", true); 
    }
});
```

You should probably write a function to keep it DRY.

Comment: Was unaware of the prop function, I like it!